# Micronaut require entities during build

Tags: jpa, micronaut

we created new application with JPA configuration. It is new application, so there are no entities yet and application failing during build with this error:

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Entities not found for JPA configuration: 'default' within packages io.example.foo
```

This error is not error because there really no entity exists. When I created dummy entity to test, build pass. Can you tell me how to fix it?

This is my jpa configuration:

```
jpa:
  default:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: none
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
        physical_naming_strategy: "io.micronaut.data.hibernate.naming.DefaultPhysicalNamingStrategy"
        bytecode:
          provider: none
```

Comment: could you provide an example repository with this error?

Comment: What is the use case for setting up an app with JPA-configuration without any entities?

Comment: I actually have one. I'm writting a tool which with should be auto configurable. As a user must be able to just use the tool and it should ask a connection string, and create enitities. it seems mist have seperate configs now.